# Problem to change from “mode: hash” to “mode: history”

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I’m having a problem to use vue-router in “history-mode”.

My local server is running on localhost:8080, so my app.js are fetching from `http://localhost:8080/app.js` when it’s running in “hash-mode”, but when I changed it to `“history-mode”` my `app.js` start to be fetching from `http://localhost:8080/profile/app.js.`

`/profile/` is the first part of the URL that my app opens…

I’m running through the same issue with my favicon icon, that are in `public/img` and uses the base_url `(href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico")` in `index.html` to be fetched.

Somebody already pass through the same issue and/or could help me?

Comment: Using history mode you've to set up your server to always fall back to the app. Therefore your app should always handle routing.

Comment: Where are you hosting? What platform are you using to host? Azure static webapps, nginx, apache, github pages, etc.